# зависимости с разными версиями библиотек в gradle

Tags: java, gradle, зависимости

Коллеги, приветствую.

**Введение**. Имеется довольно большой проект на Java с большим количеством подключенных библиотек. В кач-ве сборщика используется Gradle 4.10. Фреймворк с закрытым исходником "под капотом" ссылается на библиотеку poi-ooxml версии 3.17.
Мне понадобилось подключить библиотеку, которой требуется poi-ooxml-4.1.2. Все либы подключаются только по ссылке на файл, доступа в инет нет. В данный момент это выглядит так:

```
compile files('../../repository/org/apache/poi/poi-ooxml/4.1.2/poi-ooxml-4.1.2.jar')
compile files('../../repository/org/jxls/jxls-poi/2.8.1/jxls-poi-2.8.1.jar')
```

**Проблема**: в рантайме новая либа ссылается на классы из poi 3.17.

**Вопрос**: можно ли как-то форсировать, чтобы вновь подключенная либа ссылалась на poi 4.1.2, при этом не меняя ничего в остальном проекте?

Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Кажется, вам нужно что-то отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34343640/how-to-shade-a-transitive-dependency-in-gradle